# How long will items stick around when dropped?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

If I drop an item on the ground in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*, how long will it stick around? I am not talking about displaying an item or a pattern but taking, say, a stack of gold and dropping it some where. Will it eventually despawn or is it there for good?

Comment: Judging based on past Animal Crossing it will persist forever until it is removed by a house/event occupying the same space when it'll be moved to the lost and found (but I haven't seen a lost and found yet)

Comment: @BenBrocka Good enough for until we get a more explicit answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on past animal crossing games and judging from a week's worth of experience, items will persist forever when dropped until picked up, and they will be moved to the "lost and found" (does this exist in *AC:NL*? I haven't seen one *yet*) as soon as an event or new house needs to occupy the space the item took. In the original AC I left items all over several acres of land and they were only removed when (oops) an event cleared the acre.

I haven't noticed any dropped items disappearing so far. Note that buried fossils and gyroids are an exception to this rule; *naturally placed* buried items will be removed the next day.

Comment: The lost and found in New Leaf is in the police station, which you have to build first. The pitfall seeds certainly vanish the next day, as I found out when attempting to trick my brother into one.